# Capture network traffic between VM's Virtualbox using Wireshark

Tags: virtualbox, virtual-machine, wireshark

I'm trying to capture all network traffic between VMs (and in the VMs to themselves) running on a single host using Virtualbox for the VMs and Wireshark for the capturing. VMs are Ubuntu 14.04 and the host is Windows 8.
I'm messing about, but I can't get it just right.

Ideally, I have the following setup:

1 talking node on VM1, 2 talking nodes on VM2 and the host machine.
Using Wireshark on the host, I can capture all traffic between the 3 talking nodes without capturing packets from or to the host itself.
Using Wireshark on a VM, I can capture all traffic between the nodes on the machine itself and between the nodes on my machine from/to a node on a different machine.
I still have full internet connectivity on the host and all the VMs.

Is this possible? I can't get it configured correctly.

Purpose is to test some networking implementations and changes and be able to determine how much, for example, the overhead is reduced in total communications if I make change X.

Comment: Are you capturing all interfaces or just one?  Might be that you're not monitoring all the nics you need to be but it sounds like you probably went over that.

Comment: Yeah, should've mentioned that. I'm aware the issues of root and Wireshark and I am capturing all interfaces, i.e., eth0, nflog, nfqueue,any, Loopback:io